# Setting A Variable in A While Loop in Bash

Tags: string, bash, variables, loops, grep

I need help setting the output of the grep command below as a variable for each line.

```
    while read line; do 
        grep -oP '@\K[^ ]*' <<< $line
    done < tweets
```

Above displays what I want like this:

> lunaluvbad
>
> Mags_GB
>
> And so on...

However if I would do something like:

```
    while read line; do
        usrs="grep -oP '@\K[^ ]*' <<< $line"
    done < tweets

    echo $usrs
```

It displays weird result, and certainly not the result I'm looking for.  I need $usrs to display what I had mentioned above.  Example:

> lunaluvbad
>
> Mags_GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a loop at all.  `grep` will loop over the lines of the input anyway:

```
usrs=$(grep -oP '@\K[^ ]*' tweets)
```

Comment: This almost displays what I want, but the output is not displayed on its own line.  Every word needs to be on its own line.  Have any ideas?

Comment: @RydallCooper Use quotes when you print the variable: `echo "$usrs"`

Comment: @RydallCooper: If you just want the output, `grep -oP '@\K[^ ]*' tweets` is all you need.  If you want to do further processing on the output, tell us what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of BASH arrays and `command substitution` like this:

```
users=()
while read -r line; do
    users+=( "$(grep -oP '@\K[^ ]*' <<< "$line")" )
done < tweets
```

OR else using `process substitution`:

```
users=()
while read -r line; do
    users+=( "$line" )
done < <(grep -oP '@\K[^ ]*' tweets)

printf "%s\n" "${users[@]}"
```